# Editing A tuple. and accessing the index of tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple , and as I know its immutable, is there any indirect way to edit/add elements or remove some?

```
TUPLE_1 = (1,2,5,3,'kevin','messi')
```

I want to edit the strings and convert it to a number. And also I want to print the index of the newly added number.

Comment: if you're going to edit it, why use tuple? just use list instead

Comment: Actually i want to learn, how to edit a tuple. ..

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a list and change elements:

```py
TUPLE_1 = (1,2,5,3,'kevin','messi') 
LST_1 = list(TUPLE_1)
```

Now you can change elements. If you need a tuple back:

```py
TUPLE_2 = typle(LST_1)
```

Comment: thanks, is there a "unpacking" and packing method too?

Comment: yes, but I am not sure to what you want to unpack it. For example you can "add"  `1` to your tuple using `TUPLE_1 = (*TUPLE_1, 1)` where `*` is used to unpack the tuple

Comment: @3DsparialUser ok thanks